# Should I generate my own token after get token from 3rd party API?

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, jwt

I want to use Spotify API and therefore I've implemented Spotify API in my backend.

Maybe this question is dependent to the architectural design but I am wondering best practice.

My backend gets token from Spotify API and I store it. That's Ok.

Should I generate my own JWT token after that process for communicate to frontend? Or, Should I use Spotify Access Token for communicate to frontend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best practice in my opinion is to secure every communication path separately.

As I understand from your question your backend talks to Spotify and your frontend talks to your backend and your frontend does not know anything about the Spotify API?

In this case handle both communication paths independend of each other.